# Double delete two allocated variables in c++

Tags: c++

I got this code:

```
int **a;
int *b;

b = new int;
a = new int*;

*b=10;
a =&b;

std::cout << **a << std::endl;// display 10
```

If I do this:

```
delete a;
```

Do I delete "b" also?

Comment: It results in undefined behaviour because `b` was not allocated with `new`. It's basically the same as `int i; delete &i;`.

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself when using `delete` is: *What is the pointer I'm deleting point to?* In this case, it points to `b`. Was `b` allocated with `new`? No, and that's why it's incorrect. Note that you *could* delete `b` with `delete *a`, but this doesn't affect the `int*` originally allocated during the first assignment of `a`, which is lost forever (a memory leak) since you didn't save the value of `a` before overwriting it.

Comment: this way you lose the reference to the "new int*"... that means your code has a memory leak and that the allocated memory doesn't belong to you anymore :(

Answer (score 5):

```
delete a;
```

Since `a` was not allocated with `new`, this results in undefined behaviour.

The problems really start when you assign to `a` for a second time.

```
b = new int;
a = new int*;
*b = 10;
a = &b; // oops
```

At this point you've lost track of the object allocated by the original call to `new`, that you originally stored in `a`. So that's a memory leak.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
int *b = new int;
*b = 10;
int **a = &b;
std::cout << **a << std::endl;
delete b;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do `delete a` you tear a hole in the fabric of the universe, because `a` no longer points to that `new int*`, but to `b`, which was not dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 0):

b is dynamically allocated (b = new int;)
then we store 10 into the allocated int.

We then allocate 'a' a pointer to a pointer to int.
But then assign to 'a' which means we lose what 'a' was pointing at.
When we delete a I guess you'll get an error because it is no longer pointing 
at dynamically allocated memory.

perhaps you meant *a = b

in which case you would still have to delete a and delete b

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing your question and the code:

```
int * b = new int;  // Dynamically allocate for 1 integer.
int * * a = new int *; // Allocate 1 pointer dynamically.

// The tricky part to understand.
// The variable `a` points to a pointer.
// So dereferencing 'a' results in a pointer to an integer.
// So, assign the pointer, in dynamic memory, with the content
// of the 'b' pointer.
*a = b;

// What does this statement do?
delete a;
```

In the above example, the `delete` frees up the memory allocated for the `a` variable.  Nothing more, nothing less.

The pointer, `b`, is not effected.  It still points to memory allocated for an integer.

The deallocation of memory for `a` does not affect `b` because the deallocation function does not operate on the content of allocated memory.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. Well, it deletes the object pointed at by `b`. `a` and `b` will still have the value of the address of the original object. In order to make sure that `a` and `b` are not used improperly, try adding this:

```
a=NULL;
b=NULL;
```

Comment: No, it attempts to delete an object pointed to by `a` - which is `b`, not `*b`.